# Computing associated primes of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ over $\mathbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$.

Modulo $n$, each $p_i$ annihilates $p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_i^{\alpha_i -1} \cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$, so each $(p_i)$ is an associated prime of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

---

Here is where I'm stuck.

Now suppose $(q)$ is an associated prime. Then there exists $x \notin (n)$ such that $qx \in (n)$.

So, $n \mid qx$ and so some $p_i \mid qx$. Then $p_i \mid q$ or $p_i \mid x$.

If for some $i$ we have $p_i \mid q$, then $p_i =q$.

On the contrary, if no $p_i$ divides $q$ then $q$ is not among the $p_i$ and thus every $p_i \mid x$.

I believe we want to derive a contradiction by showing $x \in (n)$.

Comment: It would be simpler to note that all prime ideals of $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ are *minimal prime ideals*, hence  are associated. So you only  have to determine prime ideals of the quotient.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a general (commutative) ring and $I\subset A$ be an ideal whose primary decomposition exists. Then the primes associated with $I$ are precisely those primes which occur in $r(I:x)$ as $x$ ranges over all the elements of the ring. Here $r(B)$ denotes the radical of the ideal $B$.

In your case, if $(q)$ is a prime associated with $(n)$ then $(q) = r((n) : x)$ for some $x$. Obviously $x$ should not be inside $(n)$ otherwise $((n):x) = \mathbb{Z}$. Now
$$((n):x) = \left(\frac{n}{\gcd(n,x)}\right).$$

Radical of an arbitrary ideal $(b)$, where $b=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, is simply $(p_1\dots p_k)$. Hence for $r((n):x)$ to be prime we must have
$$\frac{n}{\gcd(n,x)} = p_i^{m}.$$
I think I have already over-explained.

Where you went wrong is the following. If $(q)$ is a prime associated with $(n)$ then there exists an $x \notin (n)$ such that $q^mx \in (n)$ for some integer $m$.